# Mysterious loop in jQuery function

Tags: jquery, loops

I have one problem with my function in jQuery. First I will explain what I am trying to do.

I have two elements inside a div, the p element and input element. The element p is visible, and the input element stay hidden. When the user clicks in the p element, the input element will appear (show and focus) and the p element will disappear (hide). When the input field appears, if the user types something and presses enter, a new li element will be added.

This is my current code:

```
function createFolder() {
    // Should be a clickable element
    $('#create p').click(function() {

        // Hide the p element
        $(this).hide();

        // Show and focus the createFolder (input field)
        $('#createFolder').show().focus();

        // If press a key inside input field
        $('#createFolder').keypress(function(event) {
            // If this key is "enter"
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                // Add a new li element inside menu
                $('#menu').append('<li class="expandable"><a href="#">' + $('#createFolder').val() + '</a></li>');
            }
        });

        // Focus out the input field
        $('#createFolder').focusout(function() {
            // Hide the input field element
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmCG6.png

But I have a problem, when I click in p element or focus out (3 clicks for example), when I type something and press enter, three li elements are added to my menu. It's like a loop, it counts my clicks and focus out and when I type something, it adds that number of elements. Someone can help me with this? And if is possible, teach me why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call this code:

```
$('#createFolder').keypress(function(event) {
    // If this key is "enter"
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        // Add a new li element inside menu
        $('#menu').append('<li class="expandable"><a href="#">' + $('#createFolder').val() + '</a></li>');
    }
});
```

you're adding a new event handler for the `keypress` event to that element. The important point is **adding**, jQuery doesn't overwrite existing event handlers - every single time you call that piece of code a new event handler is added to the element.

And, since that code is within the `click` event handler for your `<p>` element, every time you click on that element you're getting an additional handler for the `keypress` event. If you click three times you have three event handlers, each of which will fire when you press a key.

The easiest solution is so simply move that code to bind the `keypress` event handler outside of the `click` event handler for the `<p>` element.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var items = $('#menu').parent().children(".expandable").length;
if(items > 0){
//skip doing what you are doing.
}else{
$('#menu').append('<li class="expandable"><a href="#">' +  $('#createFolder').val() + '</a></li>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#menu').html('<li class="expandable"><a href="#">' +  $('#createFolder').val() + '</a></li>');
```